# Huge Difference in magnitude of getCurrentThreadCpuTime diff and System.nanoTime() diff for a code snippet in Java

Tags: java, performance, time, garbage-collection, preemption

```
ThreadMXBean threadBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
long startCPUTime = threadBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
long startTime = System.nanoTime();

// Some Java Code (No Network/Database calls) .....

long endCPUTime = threadBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
long endTime = System.nanoTime();

long timeElapsedCPU = endCPUTime - startCPUTime
long latency = endTime - startTime
```

The JVM was launced with verbose GC logs switch enabled and there was no GC logs while the above code was running. Then can we conclude that if there is a huge difference between actual latency and CPU time elapsed, then the thread was preempted by the OS ?

I have observed huge difference: latency more than 1 second and timeElpasedCPU a few milliseconds.

Comment: What happens if you run the code EXACTLY as you show it (i.e. with nothing where you indicate `// Some Java Code (No Network/Database calls) `?  Please try some different tests before asking here, you might be able to figure it out on your own.  Also, what are the results from `isThreadCpuTimeSupported()` and `isThreadCpuTimeEnabled()`?

Comment: @JimGarrison I saw that both isThreadCpuTimeSupported() and isThreadCpuTimeEnabled() are true. If I run the code exactly shown, there is never a huge difference between the two latencies.